# How to bind data coming from webservice to check box in html

Tags: html, angularjs

I have check box at UI side on which i want to bind data coming from web service in form of jason

Html code:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline nopaddingleft" for="radio1">
      <input name="radio1" type="checkbox" id="radio1"  
           class="checkbox-inline margin-right-five" 
           value="name" checked={{insuredProfile.isScrubbed}} />Scrub
</label>
```

The value i want to bind is:{{insuredProfile.isScrubbed}} it will be true or false

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your view use [`ngChecked`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChecked).

In your `controller` you'll need to have something like:

```
$scope.insuredProfile = { isScrubbed: true };
```

Comment: Actually i have a service which is returning data in jason format i just need to use that value in check box.

Comment: But you need that value in your scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **ng-model** for the checkbox input.
 `ng-model="insuredProfile.isScrubbed"`